# v-for not rendering list in nested route view (vue 3, vue router 4, vueitfy)

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am rendering a set of views from tabs, and each rendered view should have a sub nav list that is generated via a v-for loop. But that list is not rendering. Am I passing the props incorrectly?

I am not using a build step, just CDN and defining everything within the same scope. Would prefer to keep the data on the parent vue instance. Code below.

```
//app.js

const reports = {
    props: [
      'reports'
    ],
    template: `<v-container>
        <v-row>

          <v-col cols="12" md="2" >
            <v-sheet rounded="lg" min-height="268" >
              <!-- Reports List -->
              <v-list density="compact">
                <v-list-subheader>Reports</v-list-subheader>

                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(item, i) in reports"
                  :key="i"
                  :value="item"
                  color="primary"
                >
                  <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <v-icon >{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
                  </template>

                  <v-list-item-title >{{item.text}}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>

            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="8" >
            <v-sheet min-height="170vh" rounded="lg" >
              <!--  -->
              <router-view name="main"></router-view>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="2" >
            <v-sheet rounded="lg" min-height="268" >
              <!--  -->
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-container>`,
    children: [],
  };

const routes = [
  { 
    path: "/", 
    component: home },
  {
    path: "/reports",
    props: true,
    component: reports,
  },
  { 
    path: "/schedule", 
    props: true,
    component: schedule },
];

const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      staff: [],
      reports: [
        { text: "My Training Status", icon: "mdi-star" },
        { text: "My Team", icon: "mdi-account-multiple" },
        { text: "By Employee", icon: "mdi-account" },
        { text: "By Shop", icon: "mdi-home-analytics" },
        { text: "By Dept", icon: "mdi-home-group" },
        { text: "By Unit", icon: "mdi-office-building" },
        { text: "By Leader", icon: "mdi-clipboard-account" },
        { text: "By Class", icon: "mdi-google-classroom" },
        { text: "By Job", icon: "mdi-card-account-details" },
        { text: "All UWF", icon: "mdi-account-group" },
      ],
      schedule: [
        { text: "Schedule", icon: "mdi-calendar-month" },
        { text: "My Schedule", icon: "mdi-calendar-account" },
        { text: "History", icon: "mdi-history" },
        { text: "Request a Class", icon: "mdi-chat-plus" },
        { text: "By Job", icon: "mdi-card-account-details" },
        { text: "By Shop", icon: "mdi-home-analytics" },
        { text: "By Dept", icon: "mdi-home-group" },
        { text: "By Leader", icon: "mdi-clipboard-account" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: { },
  mounted() {  },
});

//index.html

<div id="app">

  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-app-bar class="px-3" density="compact" >
      <v-avatar color="grey-darken-1" class="hidden-md-and-up" size="32"></v-avatar>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-tabs
        centered
        color="grey-darken-2"
      >

        <v-tab to="/">
          Home
        </v-tab>
        
        <v-tab to="/reports">
          Reports
        </v-tab>

        <v-tab to="/schedule">
          Schedule
        </v-tab>

      </v-tabs>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-avatar class="hidden-sm-and-down" color="grey-darken-1" size="32" ></v-avatar>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main class="bg-grey-lighten-3">
      <router-view></router-view>

      
    </v-main>

  </v-app>

</div>
```

I am throwing no errors in console. The reports list, renders, but the only item is the header. Its as if the v-loop doesn't execute.

I assume I am passing the property incorrectly but I cannot figure out the correct method. Been over the docs multiple times and tried every permutation I could imagine. Even asked chatGPT for help. That went stupidly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: you have to declare each property in the router view tag that is the parent of the nested view that might use it. Like so:

```
<router-view :reports="reports"></router-view>
```

I would just like to say this is not mentioned anywhere in the docs. I would also like to say this is incredibly poor design. It means I either have to declare every variable that might be nested below, or I have to use an outside store like Vuex. So basically, vue router creates about as many problems as it solve. But I digress.